# Kubernetes Limit Deployment to one instance

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-deployment

I'm having a Kubernetes deployment configured in `deployment.yaml` which is just 1 replica. The replica is running a container which running a process and it's **very important** to ensure there's no moment in time when there are two instances of this process are running.

The deployment / re-deployment is something I don't have control on and happens with `kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml` whenever there's a change to the spec.

This is not great, because k8s brings down a deployment **only** after the new one is up and running.

If I had control over how it's deployed, I would have executed `kubectl delete -f deployment.yaml` and then `kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml`. However, I don't have control over it.

**Question:** how can I configure that in my deployment spec? i.e. to ensure there's no moment in time when there are two instances of the process running.

Thanks!

Comment: solved: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#recreate-deployment

Comment: Statefulset does have this feature available.

Comment: If you solved the issue, you may consider posting an answer to your own question to make it clearer for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default deployment strategy is rollingUpdate which brings your new pod up before the old pod goes down based on the values maxSurge and maxUnavailable.

Instead use recreate strategy. It will bring down the old pod, then bring up the new pod. You can configure this in your deployment.yaml file